# Best way to compare performance identical SQL queries with different executions?

Tags: sql, performance, time, performance-testing, execution-time

I'm creating a query that will contain multiple temp tables and subqueries. I want to optimize the execution time by using the most efficient method of retrieving data along each step.

A couple years ago I had a query I found online that would test a single query multiple times and output an average. It was cumbersome in that it wouldn't allow me to include temp tables and I had to manually record the results and compare them myself, but regardless I can't seem to locate it anymore.

I'm looking to do either of the following:

---

**Option 1:**

First take one of the sub queries that could be written in different ways, test it multiple times and return the average execution time. Then test it's variations and compare them to find the most efficient one. For example:

```
**RUN THIS QUERY 5 TIMES**
 
SELECT
SU.[Item No_] as 'SKU',
SUM(SU.[Current Stock Quantity]) as 'Current Units'

FROM database as SU

WHERE
SU.[Current Stock Quantity] <> 0

GROUP BY
SU.[Item No_]

**ALSO RUN THIS QUERY 5 TIMES**

SELECT
SU.[Item No_] as 'SKU',
SUM(SU.[Current Stock Quantity]) as 'Current Units'

FROM database as SU

GROUP BY
SU.[Item No_]

HAVING
SUM(SU.[Current Stock Quantity]) <> 0

**GET AVERAGE TIME TO EXECUTE QUERY 1**
**GET AVERAGE TIME TO EXECUTE QUERY 2**
**COMPARE QUERY 1 AVERAGE AND QUERY 2 AVERAGE AND STATE WHICH IS FASTER**
```

The output could look something like this:
| Query  | Query 2 | Best Query |
| ------  | ------ | ---------- |
| 5m 12s  | 3m 02s | Query 2    |

---

**Option 2**

The second option could be to look at the entire main query and tell me where the biggest slow down is. I tried using Client Statistics but couldn't make heads or tails of what section it was referring to. I also don't have access to the Execution plan.

The output for this could just tell me the execution time of each temp table/subquery but I have to be able to determine which one it's referring to, whether it's just by line number or some other means.

The output could look something like this:
| Section Executed | Starting Line | Time   |
| ---------------  | ------------- | ------ |
| Temp Table 1     | 1             | 3m 02s |
| Temp Table 2     | 10            | 1m 26s |
| Query 1          | 18            | 0m 04s |
| Subquery 1       | 24            | 2m 00s |

Comment: Why don't you have access to the execution plan? These plans are quite clever. I think it's not clever to do not use them.

Comment: Use SET STATISTICS IO ON. Runtime could be affected by many things - reads are usually a good indication of performance

Comment: Using the execution plan is absolutely cruicial to understanding the performance of a query. Using IO statistics is also beneficial, see [this useful tool](http://statisticsparser.com/) for analysis.

Comment: Identical? No, they aren't. If you get the same result it is because of poor sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) to run the queries with multiple threads for multiple iterations.

For example [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) could be the easiest option, it's sufficient to:

1. Add the [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database to "lib" folder of JMeter installation
2. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and put your database URL and credentials there.
3. Add [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler per query and put the SQL there